# Create a sharedViewModel within a separate module nav graph (Compose)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to create an instance of a shared view model (that uses hilt), to share between my 2 composable "screens", both of them are in a separate graph (because of nested navigation) and I cannot find a way to create the view model (and making the instance in the other module seems... just awfully wrong)

code:

main navigation inside MainActivity

```kotlin
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
) {
    // I technically could create the viewModel instance here, but that seems awful!
    val mainNavController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = mainNavController,
        startDestination = ProductRoutes.ProductGraph.route
    ) {
        productGraph(navController = mainNavController)
    }
}
```

ProductGraph:

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.productGraph(
    navController: NavController
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = ProductRoutes.ProductListScreen.route,
        route = ProductRoutes.ProductGraph.route
    ) {
        composable(route = ProductRoutes.ProductListScreen.route) {
            ProductListScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = ProductRoutes.ProductDetailScreen.route
        ) {
            ProductDetailScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        // both need the same view model to pass a product to display (from the list to detail screen)
    }
}
```

I'm looking for ways to create the VM in a reasonable way in this scenario

Any tips / hints / gists will be appreciated,
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can get the view model from the using the navBackEntry, it will only work if don't pop your previous navGraph on navigating to the other.

```
 navigation(
        startDestination = ProductRoutes.ProductListScreen.route,
        route = ProductRoutes.ProductGraph.route
    ) {

        composable(route = ProductRoutes.ProductListScreen.route) {
            val parentEntry = remember {
        navController.getBackstackEntry("the route to your previous nav 
                graph")
          }
          val vm = viewModel<ViewModelClass>(parentEntry)
            ProductListScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = ProductRoutes.ProductDetailScreen.route
        ) {
            ProductDetailScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        // both need the same view model to pass a product to display (from the list to detail screen)
    }
```

Comment: This actually does not work, you need to use `val parentEntry = remember(it) { ... }`, but it did lead me to the correct solution